# MySQL - JOIN, WHERE, and GROUP BY Queries

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 tables: `invoice` `order`, and `salesteam`. I want to create a query to determine the total order value for each sales representative in each company.

I am receiving an error when running my query. Could someone provide some suggestions on how to troubleshoot? Thank you!

---

**invoice**:

```
Order_Id,Date,Meal_Id,Company_Id,Date_of_Meal,Participants,Meal_Price,Type_of_Meal
839FKFW2LLX4LMBB,27-05-2016,INBUX904GIHI8YBD,LJKS5NK6788CYMUU,2016-05-31 07:00:00+02:00,['David Bishop'],469,Breakfast
97OX39BGVMHODLJM,27-09-2018,J0MMOOPP709DIDIE,LJKS5NK6788CYMUU,2018-10-01 20:00:00+02:00,['David Bishop'],22,Dinner
041ORQM5OIHTIU6L,24-08-2014,E4UJLQNCI16UX5CS,LJKS5NK6788CYMUU,2014-08-23 14:00:00+02:00,['Karen Stansell'],314,Lunch
YT796QI18WNGZ7ZJ,12-04-2014,C9SDFHF7553BE247,LJKS5NK6788CYMUU,2014-04-07 21:00:00+02:00,['Addie Patino'],438,Dinner
6YLROQT27B6HRF4E,28-07-2015,48EQXS6IHYNZDDZ5,LJKS5NK6788CYMUU,2015-07-27 14:00:00+02:00,['Addie Patino' 'Susan Guerrero'],690,Lunch
AT0R4DFYYAFOC88Q,21-07-2014,W48JPR1UYWJ18NC6,LJKS5NK6788CYMUU,2014-07-17 20:00:00+02:00,['David Bishop' 'Susan Guerrero' 'Karen Stansell'],181,Dinner
2DDN2LHS7G85GKPQ,29-04-2014,1MKLAKBOE3SP7YUL,LJKS5NK6788CYMUU,2014-04-30 21:00:00+02:00,['Susan Guerrero' 'David Bishop'],14,Dinner
FM608JK1N01BPUQN,08-05-2014,E8WJZ1FOSKZD2MJN,36MFTZOYMTAJP1RK,2014-05-07 09:00:00+02:00,['Amanda Knowles' 'Cheryl Feaster' 'Ginger Hoagland' 'Michael White'],320,Breakfast
```

**orders**:

```
Order_Id,Company_Id,Company_Name,Date,Order_Value,Converted
80EYLOKP9E762WKG,LJKS5NK6788CYMUU,Chimera-Chasing Casbah,18-02-2017,4875,1
TLEXR1HZWTUTBHPB,LJKS5NK6788CYMUU,Chimera-Chasing Casbah,30-07-2015,8425,0
839FKFW2LLX4LMBB,LJKS5NK6788CYMUU,Chimera-Chasing Casbah,27-05-2016,4837,0
97OX39BGVMHODLJM,LJKS5NK6788CYMUU,Chimera-Chasing Casbah,2018-09-27,343,0
5T4LGH4XGBWOD49Z,LJKS5NK6788CYMUU,Chimera-Chasing Casbah,2016-01-14,983,0
041ORQM5OIHTIU6L,LJKS5NK6788CYMUU,Chimera-Chasing Casbah,2014-08-24,4185,0
8QUW0UXQ3XHIL56W,LJKS5NK6788CYMUU,Chimera-Chasing Casbah,2018-09-06,3186,0
```

**salesteam**:

```
Sales_Rep, Sales_Rep_Id, Company_Name, Company_Id
Jessie Mcallister,97UNNAT790E0WM4N,Chimera-Chasing Casbah,LJKS5NK6788CYMUU
Jessie Mcallister,97UNNAT790E0WM4N,Two-Mile Grab,H3JRC7XX7WJAD4ZO
Jessie Mcallister,97UNNAT790E0WM4N,Three-Men-And-A-Helper Congo'S,HB25MDZR0MGCQUGX
Jessie Mcallister,97UNNAT790E0WM4N,Paleocortical Boatloads,NUQS9SHQH6IU92V8
Jessie Mcallister,97UNNAT790E0WM4N,Editorial Paintbrush,PQ79N68UEQ9FFCPU
Jessie Mcallister,97UNNAT790E0WM4N,Victorian Aim,93DU98KT3NZCOW58
Jessie Mcallister,97UNNAT790E0WM4N,Industrial Opinions,BQMPJF0W2Z2E0PEW
Lois Bowers,RRD2R9XMAJDP7TUY,Fantastic Re-Enactments,W2X6NP1JBOKWCO33
Lois Bowers,RRD2R9XMAJDP7TUY,Infamous Inoculation,D459BZ8Z7N1KAFGU
Lois Bowers,RRD2R9XMAJDP7TUY,Simple-Seeming Tenure,MR6NETSKD2PSN54L
```

---

**Query**:

```
SELECT s.Sales_Rep, SUM(o.Order_Value) AS Total_Order_Value
FROM salesteam s
JOIN orders o ON s.Company_Id = o.Company_Id
JOIN invoice i ON o.Order_Id = i.Order_Id
WHERE DISTINCT s.Company_Name
GROUP BY s.Sales_Rep;
```

**Error Message**:

```
ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DISTINCT s.Company_Name\n                            GROUP BY s.Sales_Rep' at line 6")
```

Comment: This is a multi-step process. Your first step is to create tables for those data files. If you have done that, please [edit] your question to show us your table definitions.  And then show us an example of the output you want, and some queries you have tried.

Comment: 'WHERE DISTINCT s.Company_Name' is not valid SQL - what are you trying to do here?

Comment: @NevilleKuyt Display the unique company names, so no repeats

Comment: Is Company_Id unique in `salesteam`?

Answer (score 0):

What you have tried to do is close to what you need, the issue in your code is the `WHERE DISTINCT s.Company_Name` you cannot use `DISTINCT` keyword in the `WHERE` clause.

**Schema (MySQL v8.0)**

```
CREATE TABLE invoice 
(
    Order_Id    VARCHAR(512),
    Date    VARCHAR(512),
    Meal_Id VARCHAR(512),
    Company_Id  VARCHAR(512),
    Date_of_Meal    VARCHAR(512),
    Participants    VARCHAR(512),
    Meal_Price  INT,
    Type_of_Meal    VARCHAR(512)
);

INSERT INTO invoice (Order_Id, Date, Meal_Id, Company_Id, Date_of_Meal, Participants, Meal_Price, Type_of_Meal) VALUES ('839FKFW2LLX4LMBB', '27-05-2016', 'INBUX904GIHI8YBD', 'LJKS5NK6788CYMUU', '2016-05-31 07:00:00+02:00', '[\'David Bishop\']', '469', 'Breakfast');
INSERT INTO invoice (Order_Id, Date, Meal_Id, Company_Id, Date_of_Meal, Participants, Meal_Price, Type_of_Meal) VALUES ('97OX39BGVMHODLJM', '27-09-2018', 'J0MMOOPP709DIDIE', 'LJKS5NK6788CYMUU', '2018-10-01 20:00:00+02:00', '[\'David Bishop\']', '22', 'Dinner');
INSERT INTO invoice (Order_Id, Date, Meal_Id, Company_Id, Date_of_Meal, Participants, Meal_Price, Type_of_Meal) VALUES ('041ORQM5OIHTIU6L', '24-08-2014', 'E4UJLQNCI16UX5CS', 'LJKS5NK6788CYMUU', '2014-08-23 14:00:00+02:00', '[\'Karen Stansell\']', '314', 'Lunch');
INSERT INTO invoice (Order_Id, Date, Meal_Id, Company_Id, Date_of_Meal, Participants, Meal_Price, Type_of_Meal) VALUES ('YT796QI18WNGZ7ZJ', '12-04-2014', 'C9SDFHF7553BE247', 'LJKS5NK6788CYMUU', '2014-04-07 21:00:00+02:00', '[\'Addie Patino\']', '438', 'Dinner');
INSERT INTO invoice (Order_Id, Date, Meal_Id, Company_Id, Date_of_Meal, Participants, Meal_Price, Type_of_Meal) VALUES ('6YLROQT27B6HRF4E', '28-07-2015', '48EQXS6IHYNZDDZ5', 'LJKS5NK6788CYMUU', '2015-07-27 14:00:00+02:00', '[\'Addie Patino\' \'Susan Guerrero\']', '690', 'Lunch');
INSERT INTO invoice (Order_Id, Date, Meal_Id, Company_Id, Date_of_Meal, Participants, Meal_Price, Type_of_Meal) VALUES ('AT0R4DFYYAFOC88Q', '21-07-2014', 'W48JPR1UYWJ18NC6', 'LJKS5NK6788CYMUU', '2014-07-17 20:00:00+02:00', '[\'David Bishop\' \'Susan Guerrero\' \'Karen Stansell\']', '181', 'Dinner');
INSERT INTO invoice (Order_Id, Date, Meal_Id, Company_Id, Date_of_Meal, Participants, Meal_Price, Type_of_Meal) VALUES ('2DDN2LHS7G85GKPQ', '29-04-2014', '1MKLAKBOE3SP7YUL', 'LJKS5NK6788CYMUU', '2014-04-30 21:00:00+02:00', '[\'Susan Guerrero\' \'David Bishop\']', '14', 'Dinner');
INSERT INTO invoice (Order_Id, Date, Meal_Id, Company_Id, Date_of_Meal, Participants, Meal_Price, Type_of_Meal) VALUES ('FM608JK1N01BPUQN', '08-05-2014', 'E8WJZ1FOSKZD2MJN', '36MFTZOYMTAJP1RK', '2014-05-07 09:00:00+02:00', '[\'Amanda Knowles\' \'Cheryl Feaster\' \'Ginger Hoagland\' \'Michael White\']', '320', 'Breakfast');



CREATE TABLE orders 
(
    Order_Id    VARCHAR(512),
    Company_Id  VARCHAR(512),
    Company_Name    VARCHAR(512),
    Date    VARCHAR(512),
    Order_Value INT,
    Converted   VARCHAR(512)
);

INSERT INTO orders (Order_Id, Company_Id, Company_Name, Date, Order_Value, Converted) VALUES ('80EYLOKP9E762WKG', 'LJKS5NK6788CYMUU', 'Chimera-Chasing Casbah', '18-02-2017', '4875', '1');
INSERT INTO orders (Order_Id, Company_Id, Company_Name, Date, Order_Value, Converted) VALUES ('TLEXR1HZWTUTBHPB', 'LJKS5NK6788CYMUU', 'Chimera-Chasing Casbah', '30-07-2015', '8425', '0');
INSERT INTO orders (Order_Id, Company_Id, Company_Name, Date, Order_Value, Converted) VALUES ('839FKFW2LLX4LMBB', 'LJKS5NK6788CYMUU', 'Chimera-Chasing Casbah', '27-05-2016', '4837', '0');
INSERT INTO orders (Order_Id, Company_Id, Company_Name, Date, Order_Value, Converted) VALUES ('97OX39BGVMHODLJM', 'LJKS5NK6788CYMUU', 'Chimera-Chasing Casbah', '2018-09-27', '343', '0');
INSERT INTO orders (Order_Id, Company_Id, Company_Name, Date, Order_Value, Converted) VALUES ('5T4LGH4XGBWOD49Z', 'LJKS5NK6788CYMUU', 'Chimera-Chasing Casbah', '2016-01-14', '983', '0');
INSERT INTO orders (Order_Id, Company_Id, Company_Name, Date, Order_Value, Converted) VALUES ('041ORQM5OIHTIU6L', 'LJKS5NK6788CYMUU', 'Chimera-Chasing Casbah', '2014-08-24', '4185', '0');
INSERT INTO orders (Order_Id, Company_Id, Company_Name, Date, Order_Value, Converted) VALUES ('8QUW0UXQ3XHIL56W', 'LJKS5NK6788CYMUU', 'Chimera-Chasing Casbah', '2018-09-06', '3186', '0');


CREATE TABLE salesteam 
(
    Sales_Rep   VARCHAR(512),
    Sales_Rep_Id    VARCHAR(512),
    Company_Name    VARCHAR(512),
    Company_Id  VARCHAR(512)
);

INSERT INTO salesteam (Sales_Rep, Sales_Rep_Id, Company_Name, Company_Id) VALUES ('Jessie Mcallister', '97UNNAT790E0WM4N', 'Chimera-Chasing Casbah', 'LJKS5NK6788CYMUU');
INSERT INTO salesteam (Sales_Rep, Sales_Rep_Id, Company_Name, Company_Id) VALUES ('Jessie Mcallister', '97UNNAT790E0WM4N', 'Two-Mile Grab', 'H3JRC7XX7WJAD4ZO');
INSERT INTO salesteam (Sales_Rep, Sales_Rep_Id, Company_Name, Company_Id) VALUES ('Jessie Mcallister', '97UNNAT790E0WM4N', 'Three-Men-And-A-Helper CongoS', 'HB25MDZR0MGCQUGX');
INSERT INTO salesteam (Sales_Rep, Sales_Rep_Id, Company_Name, Company_Id) VALUES ('Jessie Mcallister', '97UNNAT790E0WM4N', 'Paleocortical Boatloads', 'NUQS9SHQH6IU92V8');
INSERT INTO salesteam (Sales_Rep, Sales_Rep_Id, Company_Name, Company_Id) VALUES ('Jessie Mcallister', '97UNNAT790E0WM4N', 'Editorial Paintbrush', 'PQ79N68UEQ9FFCPU');
INSERT INTO salesteam (Sales_Rep, Sales_Rep_Id, Company_Name, Company_Id) VALUES ('Jessie Mcallister', '97UNNAT790E0WM4N', 'Victorian Aim', '93DU98KT3NZCOW58');
INSERT INTO salesteam (Sales_Rep, Sales_Rep_Id, Company_Name, Company_Id) VALUES ('Jessie Mcallister', '97UNNAT790E0WM4N', 'Industrial Opinions', 'BQMPJF0W2Z2E0PEW');
INSERT INTO salesteam (Sales_Rep, Sales_Rep_Id, Company_Name, Company_Id) VALUES ('Lois Bowers', 'RRD2R9XMAJDP7TUY', 'Fantastic Re-Enactments', 'W2X6NP1JBOKWCO33');
INSERT INTO salesteam (Sales_Rep, Sales_Rep_Id, Company_Name, Company_Id) VALUES ('Lois Bowers', 'RRD2R9XMAJDP7TUY', 'Infamous Inoculation', 'D459BZ8Z7N1KAFGU');
INSERT INTO salesteam (Sales_Rep, Sales_Rep_Id, Company_Name, Company_Id) VALUES ('Lois Bowers', 'RRD2R9XMAJDP7TUY', 'Simple-Seeming Tenure', 'MR6NETSKD2PSN54L');
```

---

**Query #1**

```
SELECT S.Sales_Rep, S.Sales_Rep_Id, S.Company_Name, SUM(O.Order_Value)
FROM invoice I 
JOIN orders O ON O.Order_ID = I.Order_Id AND O.Company_Id = I.Company_Id
JOIN salesteam S ON I.Company_Id = S.Company_Id
GROUP BY S.Sales_Rep, S.Sales_Rep_Id, S.Company_Name;
```

| Sales_Rep | Sales_Rep_Id | Company_Name | SUM(O.Order_Value) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Jessie Mcallister | 97UNNAT790E0WM4N | Chimera-Chasing Casbah | 9365 |

> Note: The salesteam csv data seems to have a `'` so you might need to keep an eye out and handle this when you insert the data into your tables. e.g: `Jessie Mcallister,97UNNAT790E0WM4N,Three-Men-And-A-Helper Congo'S,HB25MDZR0MGCQUGX`